# 'bluebird' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, npm, bluebird, rethinkdb

I am trying to add rethinkdb to my project but i get this error.

- I reinstall the nodejs.
- I add the path to my environment.
- I delete my proxy.
- I change to registry.

Still getting the error.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'bluebird@>= 2.3.2 < 3' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'rethinkdb'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\argestajyer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-21T08_17_58_104Z-debug.log
```

Comment: That doesn't 404 for me: http://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird. It seems like you have a network problem connecting to the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that I experienced (404 status code returned on requesting npm-package) was due the corporate proxy - Its all good now.